# How to show local html file into webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I want show my local html file into webview .I use this codes :

```
WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wv=new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv);

    try {
        InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("index.html");
        int sreamsize = stream.available();
        byte[] bufer = new byte[sreamsize];
        stream.read(bufer);
        stream.close();
        String html= new String(bufer);
        wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I can see elements into webview with out css and js effect . How to solve this?

Comment: Try adding this: `WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: camelCaseCoder :  Don't worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
WebView wv;  
  wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
       WebSettings webViewSettings = wv.getSettings();
       webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);            
       wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
try {
    InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("index.html");
    int sreamsize = stream.available();
    byte[] bufer = new byte[sreamsize];
    stream.read(bufer);
    stream.close();
    String html= new String(bufer);
    wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

And try again.

**Update**

For `JS` get works perfectly 
try

```
WebSettings webViewSettings = wv.getSettings();
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

As @Sabari preferred.

Comment: I use case and css loaded completely  but js effects don't work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
  WebView wv;  
  wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
  wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just doing `wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`?